# cast set to linkedhashset

Tags: java, set, hashset, linkedhashset

following is the scenario that I am encountering

I have this set of string here

`Set<String> attributes = new LinkedHashSet<>();`

yet I have another function with a signature LinkedHashSet

`public static List<String> rerankAttributesByType (LinkedHashSet<String> attributeList)`

is it safe for me to just cast attributes to LinkedHashSet and proceed with the function calls?

`List<String> newAttributes = rerankAttributesByType((LinkedHashSet<String>) unselectedAttribute)`

Answer (score 0):

This is technically safe, since you know the actual concrete type, but not good practice.

Instead, change

```
public static List<String> rerankAttributesByType(LinkedHashSet<String> attributeList)
```

to

```
public static List<String> rerankAttributesByType (Set<String> attributeList)
```

so you don't have to do a cast, and you can properly use the interface type throughout your program.